# Missing buttons in new Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I converted my android project to android 3.0. But in the emulator I miss al the buttons (menu, phone, camera e.t.c.). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the buttons using the Hardware Back/Home keys option in AVD Manager.

Comment: Does not help. They are still absent.

Comment: The latest version of ADT has a checkbox option "Display a skin with hardware controls" that toggles the buttons on and off.

Answer (score 0):

The tablet emulators don't have buttons.

Comment: How do I start a normal smart phone emulator?

Comment: And also when I start typing I get something like chinese text suggestions.. Little bit confused

Comment: Android 3.0 is tablet only.  You can't use it with a smartphone emulator.

Comment: Aah, that explains things. Tnx. Back to 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered this question. I am having a similar/possibly same problem.

I fired up the emulator in Android-Studio. I used the generic "galaxy nexus" image and tried to boot it up. It was very slow. And now the phone icon is missing, and so is the camera.

I can put the camera back but not the phone. Each time I boot it up again the same problem occurs.

I am running ICS 4.0 on the emulator.

I am running KDE/Kubuntu 13.04 on my computer.